# How to show marker only visible in screen android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I have project that need to show marker in map with kml, the data is about 1600 marker, i already make the program but it went realy slow sometimes it forceclose.
[image]

How to show marker that only visible in screen?

Comment: You could probably use cluster for showing 1600 marker.

Comment: You can get the bounds of the map currently displayed and only display markers within those bounds

Comment: can u give me some references about bounds? i just started learning this google map